# Usage statistics for host named site collection not including access through Intranet zone address

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

We have recently enforced SSL access to a host named site collection on SP2013. The site collection is set up with the default url as the non-SSL address and the Intranet zone address as set to SSL address.

Sxample output from `Get-SPSiteUrl (GetSPSite http://example.com)`

```
Url                         Zone
http://example.com          Default
https://example.com         Intranet
```

We are then rewriting traffic on the non-SSL address to the SSL address using the IIS rewrite module.

Since the change, the usage statistics (accessed through going to the main page, opening the Page ribbon and clicking on Popularity Trends) have dropped to zero.

Is there a way to fix this issue or do I have to change the Default address to the SSL address?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the Default zone to the https address, the statistics came back. A few other problems to do with document checking out also came right. Moral, don't use multiple addresses for host named site collection